# Jekyll Categories, how to create Enum

Tags: enums, jekyll

How to create an ENUM / or something like jekyll, so that you have control of the categories.

```
---
layout   : default
comments : true
title         : 'Servindo sites estáticos com Jekyll'
subtitle      : 'Entenda como o Jekyll funciona e como ele pode te ajudar a fazer websites estáticos.'
categories  : [jekyll]
---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a YAML list (`['Apple', 'Orange', 'Strawberry', 'Mango']`) or a space-separated string: as they explain in the jekyll Docs:
http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/index.html#predefined-variables-for-posts